# instapy() Message: Expected browser binary location

Tags: python, instapy

Hi guys this is my code

```
from instapy import InstaPy
session=InstaPy(username='login' , password='password')
session.login()
```

and this is my exception:

```
Message: Expected browser binary location, but unable to find binary in default location, no 'moz:firefoxOptions.binary' capability provided, and no binary flag set on the command line
```

Answer (score 0):

I went thru the same issue.

I found out that Instapy doesn't work with Chrome but only with Firefox.

After installing Firefox everything ran smoothly.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30671976)